# Call a script with definitions in a function

Tags: matlab

We have a script that defines values to names similar to #define in c. For example:

script.m:

```
ERR_NOERROR = 0;
ERR_FATAL = 1;
```

This script already exists and is used for value replacement when reading data from files.

Now we have a function (or more) that does some analysis and we would like to use the same definition in this function to avoid magic numbers. But when the script is called from the function we get an error.

`Attempt to add "ERR_NOERROR" to a static workspace.
 See MATLAB Programming, Restrictions on Assigning to Variables for details.`
And this does not help much in the understanding of the problem.

The question is how can we make these definitions visible/usable in the functions with having to copying it every time.

Example:

```
function foo = bar(a)
  run(script.m) %also tried running it without the run command
  if a == ERR_NOERROR
    foo = 5;
  else
    foo = 6;
  end
end
```

edit:
There was a nested function,below in the function which I was not aware of. This explains the problem.

Comment: _But when the script is called from the function we get an error_ What error? Calling a script from a function is always valid. The error is probably because of something else

Comment: Anyway, you may prefer to use [`global` variables](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo We know this works with global variables but the concept of them is not very practicable here. Because of all the declarations. Something similar to #include would be more useful, if something like this is possible in matlab.

Comment: If `script.m` is the file name, replace `run(script.m)` by `run('script')` or just `script`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem, can you construct a [mcve] and mention which version of MATLAB you uses?

Comment: The problem comes only with nested or anonymous function is used. That is why the OP's code won't reproduce this problem.

Comment: There was a nested function, below in the function which I was not aware of. This explains the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of scoping error happens when you use nested or anonymous function within a function. [The solution is well documented](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variables-in-nested-and-anonymous-functions.html).

To your case, you can avoid nested function, or "Convert the script to a function and pass the variable using arguments", as the documentation suggests.

EDIT: I should have made it clear that the error occurs even if the script is not called within the nested function. Similar scenario is that, in debug mode (by setting up a break point), it will be an error if one tries to create a temporal variable to test something.

Comment: the function is neither nested nor anonymus. And defining the script as a function, would make this more useless than global variables.

Comment: Found the problem. Below in the behemoth was a nested function. I understood that I can't do this in nested functions, but it seems that it is enough when there are nested functions present (which I was not aware of). We will dissolve the nested function and this should clear the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, rather a recommendation to switch to another method, which will not be mixing scope and workspace.

Instead of defining your constant in a `script`, you could make a class containing only constant properties. ex: code for `error_codes.m`:

```
classdef error_codes
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Constant error code definition
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    properties (Constant = true)
        noerror   =  0 ;
        fatal     =  1 ;
        errorlvl2 =  2 ;
        errorlvl3 =  3 ;
        warning   = -1 ;
        % etc ...

    end
end
```

I use this style for many different type of constants. For tidiness, I groups them all in a *Matlab package* directory (The directories which starts with a `+` character.

The added benefit of using constant class properties is the safety that the values cannot be changed in the middle of the code (your variables defined in a script could easily be overwritten by a careless user).

---

So assuming my file `error_codes.m` is placed in a folder:

```
\...somepath...\+Constants\error_codes.m
```

and of course the folder `+Constants` is on the MATLAB path, then to use it as in your example, instead of calling the script, just initialise an instance of the class, then use the constant values when you need them:

```
function foo = bar(a)
  ERR = Constants.error_codes ;
  if a == ERR.noerror
    foo = 5;
  else
    foo = 6;
  end
```

or it can works in `switch` statement too:

```
switch a
    case ERR.noerror
        foo = 5 ;
    case ERR.warning
        foo = 42 ;
    case ERR.fatal
        foo = [] ;
end
```

Comment: This is in general the idea I had. There is only the problem that these definitions have to be called this way because of spec conformity. and they are defined in a c-header. We may be able to ammend this in the future, but sadly this won't work now.

Comment: Well, it is still feasable. The constructor of the class could just load the `c` header file and parse the different values into it's properties. This can be completely transparent for the user and be called exactly how you need it to.